# Creating a program that calculates area

Tags: c#, area

I have four errors that I am struggling with.

In the WriteLine block meant to print out the areas of the shapes, both places where the variable 'area' appears give the error message: "The name 'area' does not exist in the current context". The second problem is within the class Rectangle : GeometricFigure for 'ComputeArea', the error reads "'Rectangle.ComputeArea()' hides inherited member 'GeometricFigure.ComputeArea()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended." The last error is within the class Triangle : GeometricFigure and concerns 'Triangle' in the 'public Triangle(int x, int y)' expression. The error message reads "'Rectangle.ComputeArea()' hides inherited member 'GeometricFigure.ComputeArea()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;
namespace ShapesDemo
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(8, 10);
        Square squ = new Square(11, 12);
        Triangle tri = new Triangle(10, 20);
        Console.WriteLine("Computed area is {0}" + "\n\n" + "Computed Triangle is: {1}" + "\n",
            squ.ComputeArea(area), tri.ComputeArea(area));
    }
}
abstract class GeometricFigure
{
    public GeometricFigure(decimal sideA, decimal sideB)
    {
        this.height = sideA;
        this.width = sideB;
    }
    protected decimal area;
    protected decimal width;
    protected decimal height;
    public decimal Height
    {
        get
        {
            return height;
        }
        set
        {
            height = value;
            ComputeArea();
        } 
    }
    public decimal Width
    {
        get
        {
            return width;
        }
        set { width = value; }
    }
    public decimal Area
    {
        get { return area; }
        set { area = value; }
    }
    public void ComputeArea()
    {
    }
}
class Rectangle : GeometricFigure
{
    public Rectangle(decimal sideA, decimal sideB) : base(sideA, sideB)
    {

    }
    public void ComputeArea()
    {
        area = width * height;
        WriteLine("The Area is" + width.ToString(), height.ToString());
    }
    static void Display(Rectangle rec)
    {

    }
}
class Square : GeometricFigure
{
    static void Display(Square squ)
    {
    }
    public Square(decimal sideA, decimal sideB) : base(sideA, sideA)
    {
    }
}
class Triangle : GeometricFigure
{
    static void Display(Triangle tri)
    {
    }
    public Triangle(int x, int y)
    {
        this.Width = x;
        this.Height = y;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "The name 'area' does not exist in the current context" - correct, you don't have an 'area' to pass in. Best guess you want `squ.Area` and to write code in Square.ComputeArea() to set its area member field.

Comment: You override an existing member using the `override` keyword. This however assumes the member is `virtial` or `abstract`in your abstract base-class.

Answer (score 1):

The name area doesn't exist so you can't use it. The Main() method doesn't have access to area. I think what you are trying to do is:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(8, 10);
            Square squ = new Square(11, 12);
            squ.ComputeArea();
            Triangle tri = new Triangle(10, 20);
            tri.ComputeArea();
            Console.WriteLine("Computed area is {0}" + "\n\n" + "Computed Triangle is: {1}" + "\n",
            squ.Area, tri.Area);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

But you have a bigger design problem as well. Using GeometricFigure base class is going to give you a lot of problems. I would get rig of it completely or use an interface instead. Also your Triangle needs to be:

```
public Triangle(decimal sideA, decimal sideB) : base(sideA, sideA)
        {
            this.Width = sideA;
            this.Height = sideB;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. Helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft docs have a good example of what your are attempting to accomplish here, generally you want to:

1. Abstract what is common(in this case its computing the area)
2. Specify what is not common in your concretes

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-define-abstract-properties